# Pinching for zoomin and zoomout of an image

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add pinching effect for an image..on pinchopen i want to zoomin and on pinchclose i want to zoomout an image.
I have tried using jgestures plugin..but it dint work.I am using mobile jquery and html5.it s an ipad application.

any help is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [zepto](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto)

This framework (same syntax as jquery) was developed especially for mobile devices and the beauty of that is that touch events are easily captured.

Example:

```
 $('#imagelist img').pinchIn(function(){ 
     // some function that makes your images larger
 });
```

A working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RUChL/10/

Comment: Thank u...but how can i make it work...Do i need to add any reference in order to use zepto?

Comment: Like jQuery, you include in on your page. Be careful though, to avoid conflicts, you should include jquery first, and then use Zepto('selector') in stead of $('selector') as the dollar will reference to jquery.

Comment: i have downloaded zepto and zepto.min javascripts and i have added the following code..but still pinchIn event is not detected  $('img#DocumentViewerImage').pinchIn(function() {
                $('img#DocumentViewerImage').animate({ width: "500px" }, 'slow');
        });

Comment: Hi laurens..i tried Zepto('selector'). I am getting an error : 'Reference error:can't find variable:zepto'

Comment: Was zepto included properly on your page?

Comment: yeah its included. this is what i have used  <script src="../js1/zepto.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Check this jsfiddle out. http://jsfiddle.net/RUChL/ JQUERY should be included first in the head, BEFORE zepto. Make sure you type Zepto('') and not zepto('').

Comment: I have added the reference to jsfiddle:<script src="http://jsfiddle.net/RUChL/" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js1/zepto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js1/zepto.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> AND i am adding the below code Zepto('img#imgcertificate').pinchIn(function(){ 
        $('img#imgcertificate').animate({ width: "100px" }, 'slow'); });  but i am getting two errors: ERROR1 is :"http://jsfiddle.net/RUChl/ syntaxError:parseError " and ERROR2 is :Zepto('img#imgcertificate').pinchIn['undefined'] is not a function. Am i doing it in right way?

Comment: Please change the jsfiddle to your script, and save it, that way i can check what you mean.

Comment: The problem is i dont have any plugins which can recognize gesture events(pinch).I tried jgestures and Zepto but still it is not working.I wanted to use a plugin which is supported by jquery mobile.I am new to jquery.so totally confused.Please help me..thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Please recreate the error you get in the jsfiddle, save it by clicking "update". And then send that revision back to me.

Comment: hi..i got your point.This is what i am doing in jsfiddle.but there it says "Your javascript is valid".But in the result there is no effect.Javascript is:   Zepto('#myid').pinchIn(function(){
    $('#div').animate({ width: "360px" }, 'slow');
});​

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RUChL/10/ 
There, I fixed it. Quite some syntax errors there. You should really try to read the jquery/zepto documentation.. Anyway, I put the mobile code in there in comments, and added a test-event for a click, for easier testing in your browser. Hope your problem is solved now.

Comment: hi..thanks a lot.Thats what i was trying do from past 2 days.I tried whatever u had given but  its not working in safari.Even the click event is not firing in safari.What shall i do?

Comment: Wait, I'm confused right now, the jsfiddle is not working for you? It works here, on safari.

Comment: no ,In jsfiddle it is working.It is not working When i add the same code in my project.

Comment: Ok: Make sure in your head jQuery is included before zepto. Then, your script, did you put in inline? Anyway, put the script inside the query document ready function $(function(){ your code here })

Comment: thanks.but again no result.If i create a new page with only an image,i am able to zoomin and zoomout an image.Its happening without any plugins and events,since it is a default property of ipad.But if try to do the same in my application,i am not able to do zoomin and zoomout.I tried setting user-scalability="yes" but then also its not working.Please help me out.

Comment: Aha, now i get where you are going. You just want to have a certain area of your screen to be zoomable via pinch. Take a look at http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4. Download the entire zip. There is a zoom-example. The documentation is pretty clear.

Comment: yeah i wanted to have an image to be zoomable via pinch.I had gone through iscroll4 before coming here.But thats also dint work out for me.I dont know where am i going wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot laurens for your tips.Got to know many things.I got the solution for the issue.

Comment: No problem, that is what stack is all about.

Comment: yup.For the solution refer the below link: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/InteractiveControl/InteractiveControl.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://scripty2.com/demos/touch/ and http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-multi-touch-scale-shape-with-kineticjs/